# bootstrap integration with wordpress and datatable changes whole wp-admin background as white?

Tags: wordpress, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10 and bootstrap downloaded from Datatables CDN link source.When I am integrating both with wordpress plugin, bootstrap changes the background color as white(#ffffff) for the whole wordpress admin panel and plugin page by default.Not getting why this happened ? This should not happen as i have seen in the examples.Please help me to sort this out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are probably enqueuing the CSS for whole WP admin, rather than just that specific plugin settings page. Also, if the background for body / container is changed, probably you are enqueuing some generic styles file (which sets style for body element). It's the easiest to see why this happens from Chrome's console (or Firebug or similar tool) - click "Inspect element" on the changed background, and see what CSS file does it come from.

Also you might want to check this free WordPress plugin that integrates DataTables in WordPress: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpdatatables/